# Why does OLAP subquery cause a problem when used in a view, but works otherwise in DB2 for i?

Tags: db2, db2-400

I am trying to turn rows into limited number of columns, while skipping blank rows, and return a count of non blank rows. I was able to work around the limitation, so I am more interested in a reason why the following works as a standalone statement, but fails when preceded with `CREATE VIEW TEST AS`?

```sql
with temp (id,line) as (
  values (1, 'line a'),
         (1, 'line b'),
         (1, null),
         (1, 'line d'),
         (1, 'line e'),
         (1, 'line f'),
         (2, null),
         (2, 'line b'),
         (2, 'line c') 
),
temp2 as (
  select id, line,
   row_number() over (partition by id) rn,
   sum(1) over (partition by id) rows
  from temp
  where line is not null
),
temp3 as (
  select id,
   min(case when rn = 1 then line end) line1,
   min(case when rn = 2 then line end) line2,
   min(case when rn = 3 then line end) line3,
   rows
  from temp2
  group by id,rows
)
select * from temp3
```

Running the above as is gives me the expected result of:

```
ID  LINE1   LINE2   LINE3   ROWS
1   line a  line b  line d  5
2   line b  line c       -  2
```

But when preceded with `create view test as` it gives following error:

```
SQL State: 42803 Vendor Code: -122 Message: [SQL0122] Column ID or expression in SELECT list not valid. Cause . . . . . :   One of the following has occurred: -- The statement contains column name ID and an aggregate function in the SELECT clause and no GROUP BY clause is specified. -- Column name ID is specified in the SELECT clause but not in the GROUP BY clause. -- An expression is specified in the SELECT clause but not in the GROUP BY clause. -- A column or expression that is specified in the ORDER BY clause, but not in the SELECT clause, does not conform to the grouping rules listed above. Recovery  . . . :   Do one of the following and try the request again: -- If a GROUP BY clause is required, make certain that all columns or expressions in the SELECT list and ORDER BY clause are also in the GROUP BY clause. -- If a GROUP BY clause is not needed, the SELECT list and ORDER BY clause should not contain aggregate functions with column names.
```

I know that the error is misleading, because if I remove the reference to `rows` from `temp3`, it runs ok. So this has to do specifically with the OLAP statement (`sum(1) over (partition by id) rows`) being a part of a subquery, but I don't understand why it runs ok one way and not the other. I have not been able to find documentation why this should not run as is.

Comment: Your view example runs fine in Db2 11.5 LUW. I suggest it is a defect in the Db2 for i version you are using. I suggest you raise a support case with IBM

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. I was in talks with IBM support, but they were pushing back saying it was my statement that was at fault and wanted to sell me consulting. Questioning my sanity I took to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and made it work by joining and grouping with the FK of a related table. Don't ask me why.

I already had complex queries acting funny before and had to make it work with this kind of hacks.
I'm using DB2 7.4 btw.

this works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_PERSON_KEY_CHANGE AS 
WITH changes AS (
  SELECT 
    personId, 
    dateColumn, 
    date_key, 
    CASE 
      WHEN key = LAG(dateColumn) OVER (PARTITION BY personId ORDER BY dateColumn) 
      THEN 0 
      ELSE 1 
    END AS changed
  FROM person_dates
),
groups AS (
  SELECT 
    personId, 
    dateColumn, 
    date_key, 
    SUM(changed) OVER (PARTITION BY personId ORDER BY dateColumn) AS group_id
  FROM changes
)
SELECT 
    personNames.personId,
    personNames.personName, 
    MIN(dateColumn) as date_from, 
    MAX(dateColumn) as date_to, 
    date_key
FROM groups
INNER JOIN personNames ON groups.personId = personNames.personId 
GROUP BY 
    personNames.personId,
    personNames.personName, 
    date_key, 
    group_id
```

this does NOT work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_PERSON_KEY_CHANGE AS 
WITH changes AS (
  SELECT 
    personId, 
    dateColumn, 
    date_key, 
    CASE 
      WHEN key = LAG(dateColumn) OVER (PARTITION BY personId ORDER BY dateColumn) 
      THEN 0 
      ELSE 1 
    END AS changed
  FROM person_dates
),
groups AS (
  SELECT 
    personId, 
    dateColumn, 
    date_key, 
    SUM(changed) OVER (PARTITION BY personId ORDER BY dateColumn) AS group_id
  FROM changes
)
SELECT 
    personId,
    MIN(dateColumn) as date_from, 
    MAX(dateColumn) as date_to, 
    date_key
FROM groups
GROUP BY 
    personId,
    date_key, 
    group_id
```